# Implementing a global template function as a member function that accesses members

Tags: c++, class, templates, member, member-pointers

Disclaimer: I know there are a dozen better ways to implement the following, but I'm doing it as a ways of learning more about templates and pointers to members. I'm playing around with them and I want to see if the following is possible.

I want to have a **non-member** template function that serves to act as a **non-static member** function. Different classes can implement it on their own and set which data members the function affects.

```
template <typename T, typename Y, Y T::* P>
void add10ToMember() {
    *P += static_cast<Y>(10);
}

struct DoubleHolder
{
    double value{ 0.0 };
    void(&add10)(void) =
        add10ToMember<DoubleHolder, double, &DoubleHolder::value>;
};

struct IntHolder
{
    int value{ 0 };
    void(&add10)(void) =
        add10ToMember<IntHolder, int, &IntHolder::value>;
};
```

In the example I have made the template function `add10ToMember`, a simple function that adds 10 to the given member.

As soon as I instantiate an object of `DoubleHolder` or `IntHolder`, compilation fails and the errors I get are: "'*': illegal on operands of type 'int IntHolder::* '", "'+=': illegal, left operand has type 'int IntHolder::* '".

I understand *why* I'm getting the error: `add10ToMember` doesn't actually know which `DoubleHolder` or `IntHolder` it should perform the operation on. `add10ToMember<IntHolder, int, &IntHolder::value>` doesn't become an actual member function; it's still just a global function that has effect on a non-given `IntHolder` instance.

But I just don't get what the right way to write what I want would be then, if not this. Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you trying to do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/K44W78jE3)? Beware that trying to capture `this` in any way will likely cause compiler generated special members (like assignment operators) won't work correctly.

Comment: A pointer-to-member has no association to any instance of an object. So you need a pointer/object of type `T` on which to dereference the pointer-to-member on. With `T* t` the syntax would be `t->*p += 10;`.

Comment: As `add10ToMember` cannot works because it does not know `this`, all remaining code is useless. You also have a similar problem with `add10` member that does not know about `this`. **Wrong tool for the job**.

Comment: *"I want to have a template function that serves to act as a member function."* -- More precisely, you want to have a **non-member** template function that serves to act as a (non-static) member function. The "template" part looks like a red herring to me. Can you make a non-member function that serves to act as a (non-static) member function?

Comment: @JaMiT Very true. Edited.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux As JaMiT phrased it better: I want to have a non-member template function serve as a non-static member function. I want to treat the code within the template as if it is part of a class.

Comment: @super Is there a way I can let the compiler know that the template function will ultimately always act as a member function and compile it without the need of an explicit/implicit this pointer?

Comment: @INEEDANSWERS Your question still uses templates. My point was that templates are a distraction that should be removed from your question. That is, replace the focus on "template function" with a focus on "non-member function" so that the template can be eliminated; don't add "non-member" and keep the distraction.

Comment: @INEEDANSWERS The "obvious" solution is to pass a pointer/reference to the function. You can never call a member function without an object to call it on. Then the only question left is how do you tell a free function which object to operate on? Unless you want to limit yourself to operating on object with static storage duration (globals etc) you are going to need to pass that information in some way.